# Not able to apply dns mapping in godaddy

Tags: heroku, dns

I am trying to apply the DNS mapping in godaddy. I am doing it for first time so there might me some silly things.

My application is hosted on heroku and have a link something like this `www.example.herokuapp.com`. I am trying to apply the dns mapping of `www.something.com`. Steps I have followed :-

1. heroku `heroku domains:add something.com`
2. Added CNAME host - www, Points To - `example.herokuapp.com`
3. Added Forwarding to `example.herokuapp.com`

Following these steps I am able to do the mapping or so but when I go to www.something.com it redirects to `www.example.herokuapp.com` which I do not want. I want it to be `www.something.com`. Please suggest something.

P.S. - I have also tried removing step 3 after seeing some tutorials but then it stops even to redirect.

Comment: `heroku domains:add www.something.com`?

Comment: yes added that also. but it didn't worked out

Comment: I have another query. can we map the https domain? if so please share the procedure